# quoting incorrect with onfocus using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form built with jquery.  I just want to have an empty form with onfocus set so when a user types something the text disappears.

```
var $myinput2 = js("<input id='CameraName' name='camera_name' size='24' maxlength='36' value='Enter label for camera' onfocus='if(this.value=='Enter label for camera') this.value='';'/>");
```

I get a syntax error pointing at the "if(this.value=="

I can't seem to get the quoting right so this will work.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to be careful about escaping quotation marks within a string literal if they're the same type as the whole string literal is enclosed by.

You're using single-quotes for your html attributes, so within the inline `onfocus` handler your JS should use double-quotes but because the whole string is in double-quotes you have to escape those double-quotes:

```
var $myinput2 = js("<input id='CameraName' name='camera_name' size='24' maxlength='36' value='Enter label for camera' onfocus='if(this.value==\"Enter label for camera\") this.value=\"\";'/>");
```

That is, within your string literal the inline `onfocus` will look like this:

```
"... onfocus='if(this.value==\"Enter label for camera\") this.value=\"\";' ..."
```

Such that the actual value is:

```
 onfocus='if(this.value=="Enter label for camera") this.value="";'
```

Note that you wouldn't have this problem if you didn't use an inline event handler and instead did something like:

```
var $myinput2 = js("<input id='CameraName' name='camera_name' size='24' maxlength='36' value='Enter label for camera' />");
$myinput2.focus(function() {
  if(this.value=="Enter label for camera")
     this.value="";
});
```

(I'm assuming that `js` is your alias for `jQuery`.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the built in HTML5 `placeholder` attribute.

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Comment: Thanks, this is good idea but I still need the fallback for browsers that don't have support yet.

Comment: a good idea, that article shows you how to detect if it's supported and use the fallback, but it's up to you. You can use your method for both.